# Determining size of the list top level

Tags: list-manipulation

I would like to determine how many top level list elements I have. However, I need it to work like this:

```
a = ConstantArray[1, {3, 4}];
b = ConstantArray[1, {3, 4}];
c = ConstantArray[1, {5, 4}];

noElements[a] (* should return 1 *)
noElements[{a}] (* should return 1 *)
noElements[{a,b,c}] (* should return 3 *)
```

I came up with

```
If[Length@Dimensions@# == 3, (Dimensions@#)[[1]], 1] & /@ {a, {a, b, 
   c}}
```

Which works only for list of the same shape. But I have been struggling to generalize it so that the input lists are of arbitrary shape. If it was not for the need to cover the case `noElements[a]`, I think using `Length` is straightforward.

Comment: I am confused. You talk about _top level_ list elements. Then why is `noElements[a]` supposed to return 1 if there are clearly 3 top level lists? I think it might be useful to think and explain on the corresponding [expression trees](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mu2xy.png). Do you actually want the number of nodes at the _third_ level, starting from _the bottom_?

Comment: For `Clear[f, a, b]; Length@f[a, b]`, what output is expected for `noElements`?

Answer (score 5):

You can use attribute [`HoldFirst`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldFirst.html) and functions [`Level`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Level.html) and [`Hold`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Hold.html).

```
ClearAll[noElements]
SetAttributes[noElements, HoldFirst]
noElements[expr_] := Length[Level[Hold[expr], {-1}]]
```

Then with `a`, `b`, and `c` in OP

```
noElements[a]
```

> ```
> 1
> ```

```
noElements[{a}]
```

> ```
> 1
> ```

```
noElements[{a, b, c}]
```

> ```
> 3
> ```

You want to know how many elements are at the lowest level of your first parameter in an unevaluated state. `HoldFirst` prevents the first parameter from evaluating.  The subsequent `Hold` keeps `Level` from evaluating the parameter. `Level` then picks the items in the lowest level of the held expression and returns them in a list. `Length` returns the length of that list.

Hope this helps.